# How to convert output into JSON format?

Tags: json, shell, sh, jq

I am trying to convert below output into a valid json output. 
Cant able to solve this using shell scripts.

**output**

```
svc pts/0        localhost. Tue Apr 28 21:40   still logged in   
svc pts/0        localhost. Tue Apr 28 21:40 - 21:40  (00:00)    
svc pts/0        localhost. Tue Apr 28 21:40 - 21:40  (00:00)
...etc
```

**valid json output**

```
{
    "Result": [{
        "models": ["svc pts 0 localhost.Tue Apr 28 21: 40 still logged in",
            "svc pts/0        localhost. Tue Apr 28 21:40 - 21:40  (00:00)"
        ]
    }]
}
```

is it possible to convert? can someone provide solution.s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) like:

```
program | jq -Rn '{Result:[{models:[inputs]}]}'
```

`program` being the program producing that output.

Comment: This  command was not working in jq-1.3 version, but its work on jq-1.6 version

Comment: jq: Unknown option -Rn
Use jq --help for help with command-line options,
or see the jq documentation at http://stedolan.github.com/jq

Comment: @satheeshkumar right, it may not work on obsolete versions

Comment: If possible can you share jq command which can work on 1.3 version